# Why did both my precision and recall (hence also F1) improve dramatically but the accuracy lowered?

Tags: machine-learning, accuracy

I split all the audio recordings in my small dataset into short clips, thereby "created" more samples. All of precision, recall and F1 almost doubled (from around 0.35 to around 0.65), but the accuracy lowered by a few percents (from 0.54 to 0.51). Why did that happen?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly dividing samples into smaller samples mean. In most cases, a sample cannot be divided. Can you explain this a bit?

Comment: Dividing the samples into small samples in my case is to split the audio samples into short clips of equal length, thereby "creating" more samples, increasing from, say, 44 to 550.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are doing binary classification. None of precision, recall, and F1 consider the number of true negatives:

$$precision = \frac{TP}{TP+FP}$$

$$recall = \frac{TP}{TP+FN}$$

$$F1 = 2 \times \frac{precision \times recall}{precision + recall}$$

So an explanation for your results could be that the proportion of true negatives has dropped. You should be able to confirm this by checking the confusion matrices for both results.

Comment: Thanks. I can't check the confusion matrix just yet because of a tight schedule, but theoretically, if TN drops, FP should rise, hence lowering precision, right? By the way, this is happening for both binary and multiclass.

To add to this, could it possibly imply anything about imbalance in data or a different generalising ability?